# UK tourist visa ends too soon

Tags: visas

A visa was issued to me in Venezuela for 6 months to enter the U.K. The problem is that in Venezuela you have to buy the flight ticket before they issue the visa, so my visa ends on November 18, but I am not due to leave the U.K. until November 24. My tickets are non transferable so what can I do?

Comment: You can pay a pile of money for a new ticket, pay a pile of money to extend the visa for a week, or just not do anything now but find it harder to get another visa in the future.

Comment: `The problem I have is that in Venezuela you have to buy the flight ticket before they issue the visa`. Are you saying UK visa policy differs in Venezuela from the rest of the world, where the UK Visa guidance is explicit that you do not buy tickets until after being awarded the visa? Or your visa forms were working with a **visa agent** who told you that?

Comment: The issuance of a visa should not be dependent upon flight tickets. Flying is not the only way to enter the UK (you could take a train or a ferry, for example). After all, Venezuelan citizens can enter the Schengen area without a visa, and then get to the UK in a variety of ways.

Comment: Or you can pay some money to change the ticket.

Comment: If you do not exit the UK by midnight on the 18th, you will have overstayed, a violation of the visa conditions (which you agreed to when you applied), a bad thing and one that would make it more difficult to be granted a visa in the future.

Comment: Maybe the cheaper way it is to go to an other nearby country for few days (and maybe pay for an other visa). in 24 November you just flight to UK, and you do not leave the international area of the airport. [but check carefully that you do not need transit visa]

Comment: "My tickets are non transferable" --> that has nothing to do with the dates. This means the tickets can't be used by someone else. Check whether your ticket can be rebooked.

Answer (score 1):

The options are

1. Pay a lot of money to get a new flight ticket anyway. Better inform the airline you won't be using the one on the 24th to avoid trouble down the line.
2. Jump through bureaucratic hoops and spend a lot of money to try and change your visa in line with your plane ticket.
3. Take another trip in addition to your UK trip. Venezuelans have visa free access to the Schengen zone- on the 17th or 18th leave to the UK to go spend a week visiting France, Italy or wherever you fancy/get the best deal, and then fly back to the UK on the 24th to transfer to your flight back to Venezuela.